# Generator loss not decreasing while training GAN

Tags: machine-learning, convolutional-neural-network, pytorch, loss-function, gan

I’ve been attempting to create a basic GAN to generate images using this database of flowers ([https://www.robots.ox.ac.uk/~vgg/data/flowers/102/](https://www.robots.ox.ac.uk/%7Evgg/data/flowers/102/)).

I’ve spent a few days on this, and largely based my design on the PyTorch DCGAN documentation (https://pytorch.org/tutorials/beginner/dcgan_faces_tutorial.html). However, no matter how I tune the hyper parameters, my discriminator is always reaching a super high accuracy while the generator can never significantly decrease its loss.

I am using an Adam Optimizer and a BCELoss function. I’ve tuned the learning rate multiple times. Right now, my generator has a learning rate of 0.00005 and the discriminator has a learning rate of 0.0002.

How do I allow the generator to decrease its loss?

````
import random
from torchvision.transforms import ToTensor
from torch.utils.data import DataLoader
from torchvision import datasets
import torchvision.transforms as tt
import torch
import torch.nn as nn
import cv2
import torch.nn.functional as F
from torchvision.utils import save_image
from torchvision.utils import make_grid
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import os
import numpy as np

# Set random seed for reproducibility
manualSeed = 999
#manualSeed = random.randint(1, 10000) # use if you want new results
print("Random Seed: ", manualSeed)
random.seed(manualSeed)
torch.manual_seed(manualSeed)
torch.use_deterministic_algorithms(True) # Needed for reproducible results

DATA_DIR = "main_data/" 

image_size = 64 # signficantly reduces size
batch_size = 64
stats = (0.5, 0.5, 0.5), (0.5, 0.5, 0.5) # normalizes values between -1-1, makes it more convenient for discriminator training

# number of channels in the iamge
nc = 3
latent_size = 100 #input "noise" vector size

# size of feature map in generator
ngf = 64

# size of feature map in discriminator
ndf = 64

training_dataset = datasets.ImageFolder(DATA_DIR, transform = tt.Compose([
    tt.Resize(image_size), # resizes it to 'image_size'
    tt.CenterCrop(image_size),
    tt.ToTensor(),
    tt.Normalize(*stats) # normalizes values between -1-1, makes it more convenient for discriminator training
])) # check if you need crop + resize
train_dataloader = DataLoader(training_dataset, batch_size=batch_size, shuffle=True) # batches training_dataset up and makes it iterable
device = torch.device("mps") 
print(device)

# displqy plot 
example_batch = next(iter(train_dataloader))
plt.figure(figsize=(8,8)) # 8 by 8 grid
plt.title("Training Images")
plt.axis("off")
plt.imshow(np.transpose(make_grid(example_batch[0].to(device)[:64], padding=2, normalize=True).cpu(),(1,2,0)))
# plt.show()

# custom weights initialization called on ``netG`` and ``netD``
def weights_init(m):
    classname = m.__class__.__name__
    if classname.find('Conv') != -1:
        nn.init.normal_(m.weight.data, 0.0, 0.02)
    elif classname.find('BatchNorm') != -1:
        nn.init.normal_(m.weight.data, 1.0, 0.02)
        nn.init.constant_(m.bias.data, 0)

class Generator(nn.Module):
    """This class is the template for our generator module"""
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.model = nn.Sequential(

            #in = 128 x 1 x 1
            nn.ConvTranspose2d(latent_size, ngf * 8, kernel_size=4, stride=1, padding=0, bias=False), # upscales image  (can cause artifacts, look into this)
            nn.BatchNorm2d(ngf * 8), # normalizes data
            nn.ReLU(True), # activation function that turns 0s into 1s
            # out = 512 x 4 x 4
        
            nn.ConvTranspose2d(ngf * 8, ngf * 4, kernel_size=4, stride=2, padding=1, bias = False),
            nn.BatchNorm2d(ngf * 4),
            nn.ReLU(True),
            # out = 512 x 8 x 8

            nn.ConvTranspose2d(ngf * 4, ngf * 2, kernel_size=4, stride = 2, padding = 1, bias=False),
            nn.BatchNorm2d(ngf * 2),
            nn.ReLU(True),
            # out = 128 x 16 x 16

            nn.ConvTranspose2d(ngf * 2, ngf, kernel_size=4, stride = 2, padding = 1, bias=False),
            nn.BatchNorm2d(ngf),
            nn.ReLU(True),
            # out = 64 x 32 x 32

            nn.ConvTranspose2d(64, nc, kernel_size=4, stride=2, padding=1, bias=False),
            nn.Tanh(),
            # out = 3 (RGB channels) x 64 (size) x 64 (size)
        )
    def forward(self, x):
        output = self.model(x).to(device)
        return output

class Discriminator(nn.Module):
    """Module for discriminator"""
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.model = nn.Sequential(
            # in 3 x 64 x 64
            nn.Conv2d(nc, ndf, kernel_size=4, stride=2, padding=1, bias=False),
            nn.LeakyReLU(0.2, inplace=True),
            # out: 64 x 32 x 32

            nn.Conv2d(ndf, ndf * 2, kernel_size=4, stride=2, padding=1, bias=False),
            nn.BatchNorm2d(ndf * 2),
            nn.LeakyReLU(0.2, inplace=True),
            # out = 128 x 16 x 16

            nn.Conv2d(ndf*2, ndf * 4, kernel_size = 4, stride=2, padding=1, bias=False),
            nn.BatchNorm2d(ndf * 4),
            nn.LeakyReLU(0.2, inplace=True),
            # out = 256 x 8 x 8

            nn.Conv2d(ndf * 4, ndf * 8, kernel_size=4, stride=2, padding=1, bias=False),
            nn.BatchNorm2d(ndf * 8),
            nn.LeakyReLU(0.2, inplace=True),
            # out = 512 x 4 x 4

            nn.Conv2d(ndf * 8, 1, kernel_size=4, stride = 1, padding=0, bias=False),
            # out = 1 x 1 x 1

            nn.Sigmoid(), # activation

            nn.Flatten()
        )
    def forward(self, x):
        output = self.model(x).to(device)
        return output

generator = Generator().to(device=device)
generator.apply(weights_init)
print(generator)

discriminator = Discriminator().to(device=device)
discriminator.apply(weights_init)
print(discriminator)

sample_dir = 'generated'
os.makedirs(sample_dir, exist_ok=True)
def save_samples(index, latent_tensors, show=True):
    fake_images = generator(latent_tensors)
    fake_fname = 'generated-image-{}.png'.format(index)
    save_image(fake_images, os.path.join(sample_dir, fake_fname), nrow=8)
    print(f"Saving {fake_fname}")
    if show:
        fig, ax = plt.subplot(figsize =(8,8))
        ax.set_xticks([]); ax.set_yticks([])
        ax.imshow(make_grid(fake_images.cpu().detach(), n_row = 8).permute(1,2,0))
        plt.show()

criterion = nn.BCELoss()
def train_discriminator(real_images, opt_d):
    discriminator.zero_grad() # zeroes out gradient from previous iter

    # pass real image through discrimiantor
    real_image_pred = discriminator(real_images)
    actual_answer = torch.ones(real_images.size(0), 1, device=device) # size: real_image.size(0) x 1 of ones 
    # loaded onto device
    real_loss = criterion(real_image_pred, actual_answer)
    real_score = torch.mean(real_image_pred).item() # average of all the prediction is the accuracy (since all of them should be 1)
    # Update discriminator weight
    real_loss.backward()

    # Generate fake image
    latent = torch.randn(batch_size, latent_size, 1, 1, device=device) # size: batch_size x latent_size x 1 x 1
    fake_images = generator(latent)

    # Pass fake image through discriminator
    fake_image_pred = discriminator(fake_images.detach())
    actual_answer = torch.zeros(fake_images.size(0), 1, device=device) # a vector of all 0s
    fake_loss = criterion(fake_image_pred, actual_answer)
    fake_loss.backward()
    fake_score = 1 - torch.mean(fake_image_pred).item()

    # Update discriminator weight
    opt_d.step()

    # loss and accuracy of discriminator on real images, fake images, and  generator
    return real_loss, fake_loss, real_score, fake_score



def train_generator(opt_g):
    generator.zero_grad() # zeroes out gradient from previous iter

    # Generate fake image
    latent = torch.randn(batch_size, latent_size, 1, 1, device=device) # size: batch_size x latent_size x 1 x 1
    fake_images = generator(latent)

    # Try to fool the discriminator
    fake_image_pred = discriminator(fake_images) # the exact same thing as before but without the detach
    targets = torch.ones(batch_size, 1, device=device)
    gen_loss = criterion(fake_image_pred, targets)
    gen_score = torch.mean(fake_image_pred).item()
    
    # Update generator weights
    gen_loss.backward()
    opt_g.step()

    return gen_loss, gen_score

fixed_latent = torch.randn(1, latent_size, 1, 1, device = device)

def fit(epochs, lr_g, lr_d, start_idx = 1):
    torch.cuda.empty_cache() #Releases all unoccupied cached memory currently held by the caching allocator so that those can be used in other GPU application and visible in nvidia-smi.
    size = len(train_dataloader)
   
    # Create optimizer
    opt_d = torch.optim.Adam(discriminator.parameters(), lr = lr_g, betas = (0.5, 0.999)) # Betas are used as for smoothing the path to the convergence also providing some momentum to cross a local minima or saddle point.
    opt_g = torch.optim.Adam(generator.parameters(), lr = lr_d, betas = (0.5, 0.999))
    for epoch in range(epochs):
         #Losses and scores
        loss_discriminator = 0
        discriminator_scores_on_real = 0
        discriminator_scores_on_fake = 0
        loss_generator = 0
        gen_scores = 0

        print(f"Epoch {epoch}\n----------------------")
        # Train discriminator
        for batch_num, (images,_ ) in enumerate(train_dataloader):
            print(f"{batch_num}/{size}")
            # Discriminator train
            real_images = images.to(device)
            real_loss, fake_loss, real_score, fake_score = train_discriminator(real_images, opt_d)
            
            # Record losses and scores of discriminator
            loss_discriminator += (real_loss + fake_loss)/2 # loss on fake and real images / 2
            discriminator_scores_on_real += real_score
            discriminator_scores_on_fake += fake_score

            # Generator train
            gen_loss, gen_score = train_generator(opt_g)

            # Record losses and scores of generator
            loss_generator += gen_loss
            gen_scores += gen_score

        # Log losses & scores (last batch)
        print(f"loss_d_average: {loss_discriminator/128:.4f}, discriminator_scores_on_real: {discriminator_scores_on_real/128:.4f}, discriminator_scores_on_fake: {discriminator_scores_on_fake/128:.4f}")
        print(f"loss_g average: {loss_generator/128:.4f}, generator_score: {gen_scores/128:.4f}")

        # Save generated images
        save_samples(epoch+start_idx, fixed_latent, show=False)

    return loss_generator, loss_discriminator

hitory = fit(600, 0.00005, 0.0002)
 ```
````